# The IDs change in the column

Tags: sql, sas

I am quite a novice in programming and I kind need your help regarding SQL and an issue I notice.

I have a table:

```
date,             ID,        secondary ID,     expenses
jul2020           258          0004               1000
jul2020           xxx           xxxx               xxx
......        ....               ....              .....
aug2020         258             0008               2000
aug2020         xxx             xxxx               xxx
aug2020         500             0004             1000
```

Id and secondary should be unique and always matching. But I notice that they are not. It's either correct the ID or the secondary ID. I want to sum all the D column per unique ID.

Thanks for reading and if you have any ideas would be very helpful

UPDATE: everything is numeric even ID. It's like this. As you can see we have different dates (but for the same date multiple customers). I notice that customer 258 for secondary ID 0004 during the years the ID or the secondary ID changes. And I wan to assign the same ID as the first date and the same secondary ID as the first date ( or any day just to be consistent). I want to to do this cause I want to know how many expenses each customer has during the years. There are like 50m obs.

Comment: Hi Smith_one, your question is not very clear. Could you add some more information or details, so we can help you more easily?
I don't get what you are trying to accomplish and what is going wrong.

Comment: Here's how I interpret your question: In the first row, you want Id to equal Secondary. So you change either Id to 'c1' or Secondary to 'b1'. Then you do that for all obs, so that if ID = Secondary = 'b1' for example, then no other obs can have ID = 'b1' or Secondary = 'B1', correct?

Comment: Hey thank you guys for the responses. I put more details in my description as you suggested